# Was moving this question to SE.Chemistry justified?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/saturated-vs-unsaturated-fats-structure-in-relation-to-room-temperature-state) about fats and oils was moved to Chemistry after I answered it and the answer had been accepted. I don't really see why it was moved. It is no more chemical than lots of other questions that are left in Biology. Fats and oils are natural products/biological material, and the explanation of their properties provides an underpinning for understanding the behaviour of biological membranes.

I'm pretty sure the chemists will see it as too biological.

Answer (score 1):

The question is about the chemistry of a molecule that is very important in biology. It is in the overlapping area between the chemistry and the biology site, and would be on-topic on both of them, in my opinion.

In general, I think we should not migrate  questions in this overlapping area unless the author asks us to.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the molecules in question are obviously very important in biology, I saw no biological context in either the question *or* the answer.  With that in mind I applied our guidelines for questions about bio-informatics (requiring a clear biological context) and moved it across to Chemistry, where it has gained another answer.

I did glance at how much rep would be lost by this action, admittedly I didn't clock that it was accepted and apologise for any inconvenience this caused, however I still felt it wasn't biologically motivated enough to be on-topic for us.